# How to deal with RotationGesture's angle in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture

I want to use "RotationGesture" in SwiftUI, and tried to store degrees to `@EnvironmentObject` property wrapper.

I also set the `@Published` property wrapper as "Angle.zero" in another view.

There is maybe no problem to read and write that `@Published` property wrapper at any side...

```
.gesture(
    RotationGesture()
        .onChanged({ (angle) in
            self.rotationAmount.currentUser_sDegrees = angle.degrees
        })  
)
```

but Xcode just displays

> "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context".

`rotationAmount.currentUser_sDegrees` should save angle's degree value but can't.

Comment: Could you include more of your code please? Error messages in SwiftUI tend to be quite random and usually point to wrong lines as well.

Comment: oh, I fix it to change "Angle.zero" to "0.0".